# 2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1788/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- During the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, January 19th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this new process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 13):

How would you handle this situation:

A very popular, trivial question is posted (something like: "Why don't Segways have seats?"). It receives *a lot* of votes and answers and generates a large degree of comments and discussions. It has clearly been linked to from an external source and is bringing in lots of new users, some are leaving clearly useless answers ("I like this question!") and others are leaving brief, subjective answers ("I think it is because it looks nicer that way"). It also has answers from existing site members with good reputations and include citations and well though-out reasoning.

It was posted overnight when you weren't available, and you only see this when you first visit the site in the morning. This post gets flagged as being off topic by several users, and you are pretty sure it *is* off topic for the site (it's not really about User Experience, it's more of a "Hmm, what's the deal with this thing not being how I want it to be" question).

How would you deal with this?

Answer (score 9):

A new user has left several answers to questions, and many of these have been edited by the community to generally tidy them up, improve the grammar and remove any "I hope this helps, yours, {Username}" unnecessary elements.

However this user keeps flagging these changes as well as rolling back these edits and leaving comments like "Stop vandalizing my answers".

What would you do here?

Answer (score 5):

The UX community have great stats when it comes to answer percentage, compared to other sites with the same age and the same number of users. The number of answers are remarkably equal to these other sites, but there is one figure, which is low compared to other sites: The number of questions.

[image]

The entire site generates 11 questions a day, which is half or less, compared to other comparable sites. **As a moderator, what would you do to increase the number of questions on the User Experience site?**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Comment: Thanks for your help with the default questions! They helped me spark my own question that pertains to me as a nominee.

Answer (score 3):

Where do you see yourself spending more time, *using your mod powers for good, of course*, given that you may only have a certain amount of time per day/week to give?

- ux.se
- meta.ux.se
- chat
- collaborating with other moderators
- anywhere and everywhere

... and/or do you feel that it even matters?

Comment: I would like to see chat build up momentum so I'm going to spend more time in there, keep it fun and upbeat.

Comment: @DaveAlger - Actually, you don't comment here _really_, you upvote questions (and add your own) that you feel should be asked toward the nominees. As Grace said, _"At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions."_ So if you like my question, just upvote it and then we can both answer it next round =D

Answer (score 1):

A user posts a suggestion on Meta to remove a reason to close questions. It has been decided before what is on topic and what is off topic, but this specific suggestion receives six up votes and one down-vote and is now a +5 question. What is your reply to that suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

How would you handle the situation where someone creates a flag and brings to your attention that they *suspect* ***@someone*** *is serial downvoting them* which as [**@JonW** points out in the comments below](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1769/2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/1782?noredirect=1#comment4143_1782) :

> Votes are anonymous - even to mods - so *knowing* they are being down voted by the same person is not something that can be known 100%.

This is true, but what about comments? Comments are traceable. This flag would bring to your attention that ***@someone*** is commenting on seemingly all my posts. They don't know why, maybe ***@someone*** just simply doesn't like them for whatever reason and is trolling them.

What would you do?